# Implementing nearest neighbour algorithm in Java (using dynamic programming)

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, nearest-neighbor, lookup-tables

I am trying to implement a method that executes the nearest neighbour algorithm in Java. I want to find the shortest path by executing the algorithm from each possible starting city in a table. The method is passed a `table[i][j] == table[j][i]` of the cost of travel between city `i` and `j`.

I have searched using Google, but I still do not understand how one implements such an algorithm when given a table of this sort. And this is my first time working with such an algorithm, so I have no experience with it. I think it involves dynamic programming (specifically, "table lookup"), resulting in a time complexity of O(n^3). In particular, I think it is the dynamic programming aspect of this that I am having difficulty conceptualizing.

### Edit

[This](https://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/publications/pdfs/Kumar_ECCV08_2.pdf) seems like it mentions it:

> We use several techniques to significantly improve the efficiencies of
> the different NN algorithms (in some cases exploiting the inherent
> properties of images). These include precomputing or using look-up
> tables for computing distances, ...

And see section 4.1.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for algorithms to find the [all-pairs shortest paths on an undirected graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Undirected_graph), where each city is a node and the distance between them is an edge weight. If this is the case, graph theory might give you what you are looking for.